# How to get QScrollBar state

Tags: qt

I want to get a scroll bar's state (stop or no action, move) like `onScrollStateChanged` in Android. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

See [QScrollBar](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qscrollbar.html) and use the signal that you like

> - valueChanged() is emitted when the
>     scroll bar's value has changed. The
>     tracking() determines whether this
>     signal is emitted during user
>     interaction.
> - rangeChanged() is emitted when the scroll bar's range of values has
>     changed.
> - sliderPressed() is emitted when the user starts to drag the slider.
> - sliderMoved() is emitted when the user drags the slider.
> - sliderReleased() is emitted when the user releases the slider.
> - actionTriggered() is emitted when the scroll bar is changed by user
>     interaction or via the triggerAction()
>     function.

Comment: I use value changed() to get scroll bar's value. But the value always change when I try to move the scroll bar. I want to catch the value when scroll bar stop after it move. I use a list widget and move its scroll bar without touch to the scroll bar (I click on list widget, move cursor and the scroll bar move to). `connect(listwidget->scrollbar, SIGNAL(valuechange(int)),this,SLOTS(OnValueChange(int)))` `OnValueChange(int valueScrollBar) { if(scroll stop) get valueScrollBar }` Is it possible? All I want is getting that valueScrollBar

Comment: @Eagle1987: If all you want is the value when the user stopped moving the scroll bar, then connected to the `sliderReleased` signal and in your slot, ask what the current value is.

Answer (score 0):

Since scrollbar inherits from `QAbstractSlider` it has all the signals emitted by `QAbstractSlider`. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollbar.html#details

For Eg:

```
   valueChanged();
   sliderPressed();
   sliderMoved();
```

etc.